# TFS 2012 Task board not loading

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

One of my team members made some changes to work item types yesterday.  The work item changes appear to work just fine, BUT... now the Task board does not load.  I get the error message below.  How can I properly isolate where the problem is?

> TF400917: The current configuration is not valid for this feature.
>   This feature cannot be used until you correct the configuration.

I have this error in the event log as well:

> Message System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: startIndex cannot be
>   larger than length of string. Parameter name: startIndex at
>   System.String.Substring(Int32 startIndex, Int32 length) at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.WebAccess.Routing.TfsRoute.GetRouteData(HttpContextBase
>   httpContext) at
>   System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection.GetRouteData(HttpContextBase
>   httpContext) at
>   System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule.PostResolveRequestCache(HttpContextBase
>   context) at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step,
>   Boolean& completedSynchronously)

How can I go about isolating what is going on here so I can fix it?

I would rather not have to reverse every change made yesterday one by one as that would involve destroying some work items.

Comment: What did you change?

Answer (score 0):

Try to re-import the process configuration file to your team project using **witadmin importcommonprocessconfig**. You’ll get the messages you need to resolve the error.

If you can't resolve the error, share us what exactly did you customize. The problem seems like you didn't update commonprocessconfig file.